# How can I do a recursive print using class linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, abstract-class

```
//PROTOYPE
void Display();

//CALL
list.Display();

/***********************************
*  Print the contents of the list  *
***********************************/
void EmployeeList::Display()
{
    // Temporary pointer
    newEmployee * tmp;

    tmp = head;

    // No employees in the list
    if(tmp == NULL ) 
    {
        cout << "\n\n\t\t***THERE IS NO EMPLOYEE INFORMATION STORED YET***\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "\n\n"
         << "\t\t************************************************\n"
         << "\t\t*    Employee IDs and Yearly Salary DataBase   *\n"
         << "\t\t************************************************\n\n";

    cout << "\t\t\tEmployee IDs" << setw(20) << right << "Yearly Salaries\n";

    // One employee in the list
    if(tmp->Next() == NULL ) 
    {
        cout << "\t\t\t    " << tmp->empID() << setw(13) << right << "  " 
             << "$" << setw(2) << tmp->ySalary() << endl;
    }

    else 
    {       
        do 
        {
            cout << "\t\t\t    " << tmp->empID() << setw(13) << "  " 
                 << right << "$" << setw(2) << tmp->ySalary() << endl;

            tmp = tmp->Next();

        }while(tmp != NULL );

        cout << "\n\t\t\t     ***Thank You***" << endl;
    }
}
```

I need help on what to write in order to do a recursive function call for Display function.
I need to display the list in reverse order from last to first.
How can I do a recursive print using class linked list?

Comment: To start with: DON'T SHOUT please. Rather provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Why do you need to use a *recursive* function call? A simple loop will suffice, which you already have. As for printing in reverse order, do your nodes have a `Previous()` method to facilitate that? Otherwise, just copy the node pointers to a new list that is sorted backwards, and then print that instead.

Comment: it is required in the program to use recursive call. professor specified so in the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that your list nodes do not have a `Previous()` method (otherwise a reverse print loop would have been trivial to implement without using recursion).

Try something like this:

```
void DisplayEmployeeInReverseOrder(newEmployee * emp)
{
    if (emp->Next() != NULL)
        DisplayEmployeeInReverseOrder(emp->Next());

    cout << "\t\t\t    " << emp->empID() << setw(13) << right << "  " 
             << "$" << setw(2) << emp->ySalary() << endl;
}

void EmployeeList::Display()
{
    // Temporary pointer
    newEmployee * tmp;

    tmp = head;

    // No employees in the list
    if(tmp == NULL ) 
    {
        cout << "\n\n\t\t***THERE IS NO EMPLOYEE INFORMATION STORED YET***\n";
        return;
    }

    cout << "\n\n"
         << "\t\t************************************************\n"
         << "\t\t*    Employee IDs and Yearly Salary DataBase   *\n"
         << "\t\t************************************************\n\n";

    cout << "\t\t\tEmployee IDs" << setw(20) << right << "Yearly Salaries\n";

    DisplayEmployeeInReverseOrder(tmp);

    cout << "\n\t\t\t     ***Thank You***" << endl;
}
```

Comment: but the funtion DisplayEmployeeInReverseOrder() will be placed outside the classes? where should i write the header and prototype of that function?

Comment: You can make it a method of your class if you want, but it does not need to be since it is not accessing any members of the class. It would waste more stack space to call it as a class method (each call would push the same `this` pointer on the stack over and over), and stack space usage is important when it comes to recursion. You can use it exactly as I have shown, you do not need to prototype it separately.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I also have another small error that makes the program to crash everytime i execute it. it is when i try to remove from a empty list. instead of crashing i would like th eprogram to display cout << "Employee list is empty" << endl; but it crashes instead.

Comment: void EmployeeList::Remove() 
{
    newEmployee * nextToEnd = head, 
                * last = head->Next();
    
    //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    //no nodes
    if(head == NULL)
     return;
 
    //remove the only employee in the list
 if(head->Next()== NULL)
 {
        cout << "\n\t\tEmployee ID " << head->empID() << " and salary $" 
             << head->ySalary() << " have been removed.\n"; 
        head = NULL;
        delete head;
    }

Comment: Don't put code in comments. You should have [edited your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35857918/edit) to show the code, or better [posted a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it, since it is not related to your recursion issue. In any case, if the list is empty, `head` will be NULL, so `head->Next()` crashes.  Just exit immediately if `head` is NULL, don't bother initializing `last`. BTW, you have a memory leak, since you set `head` to NULL before calling `delete head`, so the node is not actually destroyed. Deleting a NULL pointer is a no-op.